# How to access a property from an element in On event handler

Tags: jquery

Supposing I have some code like this, to work with dynamically created elements:

```
$("#content").on("click", "img.MoveUpProposal", {
    order: $(this).attr("order"),
    elemId: "",
    filterId: "",
    direction: "UP",
    targetToUpdate: "#proposalsOfReunionTable",
    urlActionMethod: "MoveProposalOfCategory",
    queryString: "?type=proposalsList"
}, ChangeOrder);
```

The dynamically created element:

```
<img src="~/Content/Images/enable_up_arrow.png" data-order="@item.SortOrder" data-elemid="@item.Id" class="MoveUpProposal"  alt="UP" style="cursor:pointer;">
```

How can i access those properties? because `$(this).attr("order")` is not working. what's the correct way?

This is the method i'll be calling:

```
 var ChangeOrder = function (order, elemId, filterId, direction,targetToUpdate, urlActionMethod, queryString) {
            var options = {
                url: '../'+urlActionMethod,
                type: 'POST',
                data: JSON.stringify({ order: order, elemId: elemId, filterId: filterId, direction: direction }),
                contentType: "application/json",
            }
            $.ajax(options).done(function (result/* , textStatus, jqXHR */) {
                if (result != null && result.success) {
                    var options2 = {
                        url: urlQuery = queryString,
                        data: "",
                        type: "get"
                    }
                    GetPartialViewUpdated(options2, targetToUpdate);
                    return true;
                }
                else { alert(result.responseText); }
            });
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: get attribute like **$(this).attr("data-order")**

Comment: What does the Microsoft Razor templating engine have to do with this?

Comment: Nothing, i just put it because i'm using it, i already took it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should have been `$(this).attr("data-order")`, However it will not work as `this` refers to `window` object not the element which triggered the event.

You need to access it in the event handler method and use `.data()` to access `data-*` prefixed attributes.

```
$("#content").on("click", "img.MoveUpProposal", {       
    elemId: "",
    filterId: "",
    direction: "UP",
    targetToUpdate: "#proposalsOfReunionTable",
    urlActionMethod: "MoveProposalOfCategory",
    queryString: "?type=proposalsList"
}, function(event){        
    var order = $(this).data("order");
    ChangeOrder.call(this, event, $(this).data("order"), $(this).data("elemId"), event.data.filterId, event.data.direction,event.data.targetToUpdate, event.data.urlActionMethod, event.data.queryString);
});
```

Comment: That way i'm getting everything undifined inside the function

Comment: I'm trying to keep those functions as generic as possible. Do you think thats a good way of doing it?

Comment: @Nmaster88, Yes that a better way. You event don't need `this`, So you can change to `ChangeOrder($(this).data("order"), ....`

Comment: I just don't understand why i need to pass an extra argument in ChangeOrder.Call (event or this) if i don't pass it i get one argument less in the function... doesn't make much sense